# Function that returns the data URI Base64 string of image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, encoding, base64, data-uri

I'm really struggling to write a function for getting the Base64 encoding of an image. Since this function will be part of a bigger script that uses jsPDF.js to make PDFs on-the-fly from a website, It's important the be able to calculate those Base64 encodings as the result of a function. The images will be hosted on the same server, so no same-origin issues. I know the **.toDataURL()** method of the canvas element can do this and I also know that the image needs to be fully loaded in order to get the Data URL correctly, so I wrote this function

```
// Encode image to Base64
function encodeBase64(url, format)
{
    var image = new Image(),
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function ()
    {
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(format);
        alert(dataURL);
    };
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to "extract" the dataURL value from the onload function so that the encodeBase64 function simply returns that value and I can put it in an array. Alert returns that string correctly so I'm sure the code works, but if I try to write any other statement like "return dataURL" or similar I just get **undefined** value. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First load all the images into an array.

Then create the dataURLs using canvas and load the dataURLs into a second array.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fbdb3qbw/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // array for dataURLs
    var dataURLs=[];

    // put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
    var imageURLs=[];  
    // push all your image urls!
    imageURLs.push({url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sun.png",format:null});
    imageURLs.push({url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/temp1.png",format:'image/jpeg'});

    // the loaded images will be placed in images[]
    var imgs=[];

    var imagesOK=0;
    loadAllImages(start);

    function loadAllImages(callback){
        for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.format=imageURLs[i].format;
            imgs.push(img);
            dataURLs.push('');
            img.index=imgs.length-1;
            img.onload = function(){ 
                imagesOK++; 
                if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                    callback();
                }
            };
            img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
            img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
            img.src = imageURLs[i].url;
        }      
    }

    function start(){

        // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
        // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

        // now loop through each img and create its dataURL
        for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
            var img=imgs[i];
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            dataURLs[img.index] = canvas.toDataURL(img.format);    
        }

        // Demo: report the results to the console
        console.log(dataURLs);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Fetch dataURLs from images (see results in the console)</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Addition: pulling urls from textarea ]**

Here's how to pull the urls from the textarea.

(#loadImages is a button that's pushed when your user has typed the urls into the textbox).

I haven't looked at the jsPDF source so I can't speak to your `dims` issue.

```
$('#loadImages').click(function(){    
    var inputText = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++){
        imageURLs.push({url: inputText[i],format:"image/jpeg"});
    }    
    loadAllImages(start);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to edit your code so that the urls are taken from a textarea input, so I replaced the imageURLs.push(...) parts with something like this
`var inputText = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) { imageURLs.push({url: inputText[i],format:"image/jpeg"});
}`
However, when using the jsPDF plugin the console says "dims is undefined". I found out that "dims" is an array referring to the jpeg size extracted from the base64 string, so there's something altering the string in the split method or textarea! Could you help?

Comment: Pulling URLs from a textarea isn't a problem--see my appended answer.